# LaTeX3: Peek for spaces

Tags: expl3

I don't get space-observing look-aheads right. What am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \testInNormalLaTeXSyntax #1
  { \intern: #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \intern:
  {
    \peek_charcode:NTF A
      { (next~token~is~A)~ }
      { 
        \peek_charcode:NTF ~
          { (next~token~is~space)~ }
          { (next~token~is~neither~nor)~ }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Hello, world with spaces!\\
\testInNormalLaTeXSyntax{AA}\\
\testInNormalLaTeXSyntax{bA}\\
\testInNormalLaTeXSyntax{ A}
\end{document}
```

White the first test works (AA), but the code line `\peek_charcode:NTF ~` breaks things.

Comment: That is the exact same thing as writing `\foo ` so the spaces is “gobbled”. May be you want `\c_space_token`?

Comment: @Manuel, that's it! I was thinking so complicated and the answer was so simple. Make your comment an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `~` is nothing more than a space, and it works exactly like always: `\foo    \bar` is the same as `\foo\bar`…

In that case what you are looking for is `\c_space_token`, which is a stored space token, thus

```
\peek_charcode:NTF \c_space_token
```

should work.

Comment: Perhaps not that `~` is specifically excluded from being an `N`-type argument

Comment: @JosephWright I'm not sure what do you mean… It's not “specifically excluded” but “generally excluded” (as *any* space token after a control sequence), or you mean something different? If you want a tokenized space you need something like, e.g., `\use:nn { \token_new:NN \c_space_token } { ~ }`.

Comment: Spaces (`~`) and grouping braces (`{` and `}`) are not `N`-type arguments and so should never be expected to work as such. That's the reason that we have `\peek_after:Nw` and `\exp_after:wN` and not `:NN` signatures, for example. So `\use:nn { \token_new:NN \c_space_token } { ~ }` is still formally forbidden, even though it would work at present.

Comment: Okey, I understood. `N` are never `{`, `}` or `~` (space), in case those will be expected in an argument, that argument will be `w`. Then `\cs_set_eq:NN` doesn't need the `=~` but only `=` in its definition. And `\token_new:NN` should be `\token_new:Nw`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I raised the business about `\cs_set_eq:NN` with the team. Position there is simple: only `N`-type args are allowed, and the `=~` in the definition is something that might change. On `\token_new:NN`, the entire `token` module is a bit of a mess: we haven't yet got to a point where we know what is really needed! I'd say 'expect changes'.